# VUEJS remove added routes or clear added routes

Tags: vue.js

Good Day Everyone,

I'm trying to remove the addedRoutes on vuejs.. after doing hours of research on vue-router documentation I can't find a method that can clear the addedRoutes.

**Here's my code:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router:router,
  data(){
      return{
          isAuth:null
      }
  },
  created(){

        this.checkAuthentication();
        if(this.isAuth){
            this.getUserRole();
        }
        bus.$on('reload', (passData) => {
            this.getUserRole();
            if(this.isAuth){
               this.getUserRole();
            }
        });
  },
  methods:{
      getUserRole(){
          this.$http.get('api/users/getRole').then(response => {
              console.log(response);
              if(response.body.is_admin){
                router.addRoutes(Routes);
              }else if(response.body.is_buh){
                router.addRoutes(BUHRoutes);
              }else if(response.body.is_so) {

              }
          });
      },
      checkAuthentication(){
          this.isAuth = this.$auth.isAuthenticated();
      }
  }
});
```

my scenario is that when I login and if it is successful I get the userRole and based on that user role I add the routes `router.addRoutes()` based on the userRole. however, when I logout I get this warning on my console log `[vue-router] Duplicate named routes definition: { name: "division-maintenance", path: "/division-maintenance" }`. that's why I was doing a research on how to clear the addedRoutes.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think there's currently no way to remove it. But [there seems to be a way to reset the entire router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1234#issuecomment-357941465)

Comment: hi @JacobGoh it's a bit confusing... my last resort is to refresh the browser when user logout.. also that also came to my mind that I need to reinitialize the router... but on the example that you just sent it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I create a example file with vue-route

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  base: process.env.BASE_URL, //config url base
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})
```

The property `mode: 'history'` removes `#`

Comment: Thanks, for the solution feedback, It helped me save a lot many hours and from a nightmare too.